# Is WebHttpBinding uses TCP connection pooling?

Tags: wcf, connection-pooling, wcf-binding, webhttpbinding

I can see in MSDN page that NetTcpBinding in new .NET 4.5 uses TCP connection pooling based on the service’s host DNS name and the port number the service is listening on. Does it true for WebHttpBinding as well? I could not find answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that connection pooling is allowed for tcp (TcpConnectionPoolSettings) and Named pipes (NamedPipeConnectionPoolSettings) only.

See also [this msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is done baased on the ServicePointManager/ServicePoint classes and so ServicePointManager MaxServicePoints/MaxServicePointIdleTime are used to control the caching.